# Sweetalert with delete action into database

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, sweetalert

Im using bootstrap template. In table I have delete button, clicking on it, Im able to display a confirmation message with **swal**. But after clicking yes,delete it.... it has perform action by deleting from database. Please guide me how to write a query in swal so that it takes that particular row id and delete that row into database.

deleting action should be like

```
if(isset($_POST['delete'])) {
$update=$_POST['v_id'];
mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE vendor_pricing SET status = 'deleted' where Vendor_pricing_id=$update");
```

}

[image: swal confirmation display]

```html
<?php
session_start();
if(empty($_SESSION))
{
  header("Location: ../login.php");
}
$mpage = "printer";
$page = "list_printer.php";

include '../header.php';
 $email1 = $_SESSION['email'];
 $Vendor_id="SELECT Vendor_id FROM vendors where email = '$email1' ";
 $result=mysqli_query($conn,$Vendor_id);
 $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
 
 $sql = "SELECT Vendor_pricing_id, status, printer_name,process,material,color,strength,surface_finish,per_gram_charge,per_hour_charge FROM vendor_pricing where Vendors_Vendor_id= $row[0] and status='active' or status='inactive' ";
      $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
      if (!$query) {
       die ('SQL Error: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
      }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
  <div class="content-wrapper">
    <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
    <section class="content-header">
      <h1>
        Printer Lists
   
      </h1>
      <ol class="breadcrumb">
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Printer</a></li>
        <li class="active">List Printers</li>
      </ol>
    </section>

    <!-- Main content -->
    <section class="content">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
         <div class="box table-responsive no-padding">
            <div class="box-header">
              <h3 class="box-title">List of all Printers</h3>
            </div>
            <!-- /.box-header -->
            <div id="response" class="box-body">
   
              <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered" style="width:100%">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>ID</th>
                                            <th width="8%">Printer Name</th>
                                            <th>Process</th>
           <th>Material</th>
                                            <th>Color</th>
                                            <th>Strength</th>
                                            <th>Surface Finish</th>
           <th padding>per Gram</th>
                                            <th>per Hour</th>
           <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <?php
  
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
  {
   $vid=$row['Vendor_pricing_id'];
   $p_name=$row['printer_name'];
   $pro=$row['process'];
   $mat=$row['material'];
   $color=$row['color'];
   $type=$row['strength'];
   $sur=$row['surface_finish'];
   $p_gram=$row['per_gram_charge'];
   $p_hour=$row['per_hour_charge'];
   $st=$row['status']; if ($st=="active"){ $link='inactive'; $color1='success'; $style='white'; $cursor='allowed'; $tip="inactive ur printer";} 
      else { $link='active';$color1='warning'; $style='#EEE'; $cursor='not-allowed'; $tip="activate ur printer";}
  
           
       ?>
<tr style="background-Color:<?php echo $style;?>; cursor: <?php echo $cursor;?>;">
     <form method="post">
     <td><?php echo $vid;?>
     <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $vid;?>" name="v_id">
     </td>
     <td><?php echo $p_name;?></td>
     <td><?php echo $pro;?></td>
     <td><?php echo $mat;?></td>
     <td><?php echo $color;?></td>
     <td><?php echo $type;?></td>
     <td><?php echo $sur;?></td>
     
                    
    
                    <button type="delete" name="delete" value="<?php echo $vid;?>" id="<?php echo $vid ?>"  type="submit" class="btn-warning"  onclick="archiveFunction(this.id)">Delete</button>

      </td>
      
     </tr>
      </form> 
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();   
});

$('#reloadpage').click(function() {
 
    location.reload(true);
 
});

function archiveFunction(id) {
event.preventDefault(); // prevent form submit
var form = event.target.form; // storing the form
        swal({
  title: "Are you sure?",
  text: "But you will still be able to retrieve this file.",
  type: "warning",
  showCancelButton: true,
  confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
  confirmButtonText: "Yes, Delete it!",
  cancelButtonText: "No, cancel please!",
  closeOnConfirm: false,
  closeOnCancel: false
},
function(isConfirm){
  if (isConfirm) {
   window.location.href="delete.php?delete_id="+id;
    swal("Updated!", "Your imaginary file has been Deleted.", "success");   

  } else {
    swal("Cancelled", "Your file is safe :)", "error");
  }
});
}
 

</script>
 
  
  </tbody>
        </table>
       </div>
            <!-- /.box-body -->
          </div>
          <!-- /.box -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.col -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.row -->
    </section>
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: where you printing the buttons you use the variable `$v_id` instead of  `$vid`

Comment: sorry sir,, its vid,, but it still it doesnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the v_id from `post` variables in php, but you are actually requesting the server with `get` method. This is the reason why it is not working. The proper way is to request the server with `post` method to perform delete action.

You should change this snippet from:

```
if (isConfirm) {
    // this is `get` request to the server
    // so you can only get the data from $_GET variable, says $_GET['delete_id']
    window.location.href = "delete.php?delete_id=" + id;
    swal("Updated!", "Your imaginary file has been Deleted.", "success");

} else {
    swal("Cancelled", "Your file is safe :)", "error");
}
```

TO

```
if (isConfirm) {
    // this is `post` request to the server
    // so you can get the data from $_POST variables, says $_POST['delete'] $_POST['v_id']
    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        data: {'delete': true, 'v_id' : id },
        url: 'delete.php',
        success: function(data) {

        }
    });
    swal("Updated!", "Your imaginary file has been Deleted.", "success");

} else {
    swal("Cancelled", "Your file is safe :)", "error");
}
```

Comment: sir, its not taking v_id,,, any suggestion where im goin wrong

Comment: can you debug and see if the value passing correctly in both javascript / php sides? in javascript side you could simply `console.log(id)` and check the `console` in `developer tool`, and for php side you could `var_dump($_POST)` and check the output

Comment: thank u sir,,it helped me to understand functionality... its taking id now

Answer (score 1):

You can create AJAX request like this:

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'GET',
    data: {'id' : this.id },
    url: 'delete.php',
    success: function(data) {
        // Request is successful you have the response in data
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('click', '.delete', function () {
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    swal({
        title: 'Are you sure?',
        text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
        type: 'warning',
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
        cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
        confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!',
    }).then((result) => {
        if (result.value) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'delete.php?action=delete',
                type: 'POST',
                data: 'id=' + id,
                dataType: 'json'
            })
                .done(function (response) {
                    swal('Deleted!', response.message, response.status);
                    fetch();
                })
                .fail(function () {
                    swal('Oops...', 'Something went wrong with ajax !', 'error');
                });
        }

    })

});
```